# How to store natsort value

Tags: php, natsort

I have alphanumeric  values which I sorted using **natsort**. The code is -

```
$getPlatform = $conn->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT platform FROM tooldata');
$getPlatform->execute();
    while($row = $getPlatform->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {  
      foreach($row as $key) { 
        $platform[] = $key; 
      }
    }
natsort($platform);
```

Now I am stuck with how to store the value os this natsort in an array ?
I tried using foreach but it gives error.
Please help.
I am very new to php.

Comment: I tired this and it returns 1 .. thts all :(

Comment: That is what I am saying , it returns a boolean value. Do a `print_r($platform);` after the `natsort` to see your sorted array.

Comment: it give the output - [key_output](http://pastebin.com/hurY12r8)

Answer (score 1):

The `natsort` returns a boolean value and so you should not store it. It will directly apply the sorting on the original array.

Comment: but I want to use these value on the x-axis of my graph.

Is there any other way to sort such values ?

Comment: Is `natsort` working for you ? Can you post the output ?

Answer (score 0):

natsort accept argument by reference. It mean whatever changes made by natsort function will be reflected in original array.

```
natsort($platforms);
print_r($platforms);
```

The other option could me sort data directly from Database, but it won't do natural sorting.

```
$getPlatform = $conn->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT platform FROM tooldata ORDER BY platform');

$getPlatform->execute();

    while($row = $getPlatform->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {  
        foreach($row as $key) 
            { 
                $platform[] = $key; 
            }
  }

print_r($platform);
```

Comment: `ORDER BY` and `natsort()` isn't the same thing.

Comment: natsort is a natural sorting while order by works on alphanumeric sorting. i.e. ("A1", "B1", "B10", B2"); natsort output will be (A1,B1,B2,B10) while order by output will be (A1,B1,B10,B2). :)

Comment: @Jack thn how I can do correct alphanumeric sorting and use it as array for the graph ?

Comment: @Trinity - thn how I can do correct alphanumeric sorting and use it as array for the graph ?